# Java optional null pointer exception

Tags: java, option-type

I am trying to use optionals for the first time and am getting a NPE with the below code.

```
Optional.ofNullable(getCustomer())
            .ifPresent(customer ->
                {
                    if (!customer.isEnabled())
                    {
                            //Error
                    }
               }
         );
```

When debugging, I can see that getCustomer() returns a valid Customer but when the ifPresent block is executed apparently customer is null.

Can anyone enlighten me as to what I have done wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: You sure it returns a valid customer? What happens if you print the customer before the if check?

Comment: please provide the error message you get

Comment: could you please provide some more code from the inside of if-enabled branch?

Comment: @Koekje Yes I can print the customer to the console in the line before this and I can execute other methods on the customer from the debugger on this line... its only once it goes into the ifPresent block that the "customer" variable doesnt seem to be assigned correctly.

Comment: I actually meant printing it inside the lambda passed to the ifPresent :) Or of course putting a breakpoint on the if statement.

Comment: @FMC Occams razor would probably point to the NPE residing somewhere in the `isEnabled` function or elsewhere in your code rather than the method passed to Optionals `ifPresent` being executed with a NULL argument.

Comment: My guess: `isEnabled()` returns a `Boolean`, and it's null.  The `!` operator then throws a NPE during unboxing.

Comment: Your code works fine for me (once I provide a minimal `Customer` class for it to work with).  The problem is not in what you present, and indeed, the stack trace should have already told you so.

Comment: Thank you everyone... after the comments here I checked and it is indeed the isEnabled thats causing the NPE and not the optional. Thanks

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes you're right the stacktrace should have... I just assumed it was the customer that was null and not the isEnabled value as when I was debugging in the lambda it wasn't able to evaluate customer. I'll be more careful :)